# Duplicate values from array for new array with python

Tags: python, numpy

My input array is: [ 37.  -18.   27.]

Now I wanted to create such array (every value four times):
[ 37.  37.  37.  37.  -18. -18.  -18.  -18.  27.  27.  27.  27.]

```
import numpy as np
abc = (37.0, -18.0, 27.0)
xyz = np.array(abc)
for i in range(len(xyz)):
    four = (xyz[i], xyz[i], xyz[i], xyz[i])
```

Now, the output isn't the right one. I want to have an one-dimensional array as a result.
Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: Where can I find this answer?

Comment: Please, give me a link.